# Original works of great mathematicians

Tags: reference-request, math-history, big-list

In almost every mathematical text there is a line as *This was first proved by Gauss* or *This formula first appeared in a work of Riemann*, but for me it's more like *My friend told me once that...*

For my Bachelor thesis and other papers I'm working on I would prefer to add a scan of the original paper rather that a quote from a book1 that quoted book2 that found it in a book3. I was already looking for some original papers from some great mathematicians (Riemann, Euler, Cantor, Hilbert etc...) on the internet, but I got quite disappointed by results. I expected some organization that collects scans from the old scientific works and makes them publicly available, but either I was looking elsewhere or it just doesn't exist...

So my question is:
**Do you know about any place (website?) where scans of original work of great old mathematicians are collected?**

> Look, the scan of the first page of Riemann's original work [Über die Anzahl der Primzahlen unter einer gegebenen Grösse](http://www.dcne.ugto.mx/Contenido/revista/numeros/17/riemann_archivos/image138.jpg) !! Such a mathematical and historical gold...

Comment: Try the following site from Goettingen University for papers in german.. and latin (mostly) by old authors. There're also works in english, french, and you can find there Euler, Sylvester, Laurent, Cantor, Gauss, etc.: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/en/dms/colbrowse/?tx_goobit3_search%5Border%5D=0&tx_goobit3_search%5BDC%5D=mathematica&tx_goobit3_search%5Blink%5D=0

Answer (score 12):

http://archive.org

Just search for "Bernhard Riemann", for example.

Answer (score 11):

This is a useful aggregation site:

[http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Erehmann/DML/dml_links.html](http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/~rehmann/DML/dml_links.html)

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about this aggregation site. I usually only use JSTOR, NUMDAM, and GDZ. This is very handy.

Answer (score 8):

For Euler see the [Euler Archive](http://www.eulerarchive.org).
For many old books see the french [Gallica](http://gallica.bnf.fr)
(the cited archive.org and gdz are great ressources too).

Don't forget [google books](http://books.google.com) and [google scholar](http://scholar.google.com) (for papers).

A [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_important_publications_in_mathematics) of important papers by wikipedia...

Answer (score 7):

Try the [European Cultural Heritage Online](http://echo.mpiwg-berlin.mpg.de/home).  I used it to look at the original pages of Thomas Harriot's [Artis Analyticae Praxis](http://echo.mpiwg-berlin.mpg.de/ECHOdocuView?pn=7&ww=1&wh=1&url=/mpiwg/online/permanent/library/BA62Z95Q/pageimg&mode=imagepath) published in 1631.

Comment: Here's the link for mathematics-related works: http://echo.mpiwg-berlin.mpg.de/content/mathematics/mathematics

Answer (score 7):

[Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/) is another potential source, although of the people mentioned above the only result I found was a book by Gauss:  [General Investigations of Curved Surfaces of 1827 and 1825](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/36856).

Comment: Just a note: Though I highly endorse Project Gutenberg's math collection, the original page scans aren't available there. (For books I've digitized for PG, the scans came either from the Internet Archive, or from volunteers at Distributed Proofreaders.) (+1.:)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some useful links I found over the years that haven't been listed here yet:

- [Rare Book Room](http://www.rarebookroom.org/)
- [The University of Michigan Historical Mathematics Collection](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/)

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if there are webpages yet to be discovered that collect collected works. If not it would be a great resource.

Here I stumbled on Weierstrass's complete works:

https://archive.org/details/mathematischewer03weieuoft

Answer (score 0):

There are two books by E.T.Bell, (1) Men of Mathematics (2) Development of Mathematics.
The first one contains biographies of almost all great mathematicians from Archimedes to Henri Poincare, and contains wealth of information about their great works. The second book contains very unique and beautiful description about how mathematics evolved, right from numbers, plane geometry to modern branches like algebraic geometry. Every body interested in Mathematics would love to read these books.

Comment: Be aware that many people think that "Men of Mathematics" is often incorrect. A second source for any of its statements would be useful.

Comment: Bell is known to have taken a fair amount of liberties in his write-up. The bit on Galois is among the more notoriously romanticized ones...